# Javascript exception: encodeUri is undefined

Tags: javascript

Right now I'm trying to use **encodeUri()** in on of my scripts, but receive the exception in topic.
The value passed to **encodeUri()** is valid and it happens in different (latest) browsers.

Anyone got an idea why it's even possible to receive an "undefined" exception for **encodeUri()**?

Btw. it's the same with **encodeUriComponent()**. Only **escape()** throws no exception.

Any help is really appreciated

Cheers,
Tom

Comment: `encodeURI` or `encodeURIComponent`

Comment: Maybe it's because both those functions are `encodeURI..`, case matters

Comment: Seems I should have a break X-) It was the case sensitive issue ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**encodeURIComponent(** *string* **)** returns "undefined" in case if *string* argument is *undefined*.

I'd suggest you to debug it and make sure that string is valid.

Also you could try to wrap this function with another function to add manual validation:

```
function encode(string) {
      var stringIsInvalid = string === undefined ||
                            typeof string !== 'string' ||
                            string.length < 1;

      if(stringIsInvalid) throw new Error('Cannot encodeURIComponent(string),'+
                                          ' string is invalid');

      return encodeURIComponent(string);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

To complete this thread for others, second solution is: Always pay attention to correct typing: encode**URI**()

Comment: I think you mean correct casing?